# NetSuite Saved Searches I want to use the ship date and deduct 7 working days from it

Tags: netsuite

I am new to formulas on NetSuite Saved Searches but need some help.  I want to use the ship date and deduct 7 working days from it

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Netsuite is based on Oracle database, so if you need any special calculation, just check how to do it using Oracle SQL. In your case, you just need to add a Formula result column of type Date and use the formula:

```
TO_DATE({internalid_shipdate_field} - 7)
```

Comment: Thank you for the above and yes will keep in mind what you said.  Looking at the question what i should have said is that I need the deduction of business working days which would exclude weekends, which is where i believe it gets a bit more complicated?

Comment: I see, but if I'm not wrong, if you have 2 days off each week, then deducing 9 days will always mean 7 working days. But if you want also to deduce variable holidays, then I don't think that this can be done using a Search

Comment: Thank you, but let me give you an example, i have a ship date of the 23/05/2022 i want to deduct 7 business days = 12/05/2022, however if i used your method it would come to  14/05/2022 which is a Saturday and would be incorrect ?

Comment: Well, I think this won't be possible using a simple Search

Answer (score 0):

You can add the formula in the formula(date) field in SS:-

```
CASE 
    WHEN to_char({shipdate},'DY') = 'MON' THEN {shipdate} - 11
    WHEN to_char({shipdate},'DY') = 'TUE' THEN {shipdate} - 11
    WHEN to_char({shipdate},'DY') = 'WED' THEN {shipdate} - 9
    WHEN to_char({shipdate},'DY') = 'THU' THEN {shipdate} - 9
    WHEN to_char({shipdate},'DY') = 'FRI' THEN {shipdate} - 9
    WHEN to_char({shipdate},'DY') = 'SAT' THEN {shipdate} - 9
    WHEN to_char({shipdate},'DY') = 'SUN' THEN {shipdate} - 10
END
```

[Table to show how I get the no. of days to deduct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TDoa.png)

Comment: Thank you very much this worked a treat! where can i learn how to write these types of formulas, very keen and interested in learning more!

Comment: Glad that this help. I learned a lot of SS formula from SuiteAnswer in NetSuite. There may not be direct answer to your question so have to steal some ideas to test and tweak to fit your requirements. For your case can try search "saved search date difference exclude weekend" you can see there are many examples with similar formula. :) #HappyLearning !

Comment: thank you again and yes i am learning on the job!